# xgboost error: dtypes must be int, float or bool, but they are

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have a preprocessed real estate related `DataFrame` with the following data types:

```
>> df.dtype

OHE_Cat__x0_Single Family Residential      Int64
OHE_Cat__x0_Townhouse                      Int64
OHE_Cat__x1_1                              Int64
OHE_Cat__x1_2                              Int64
ZIP OR POSTAL CODE                         Int64
PRICE                                      Int64
BEDS                                       Int64
BATHS                                    Float64
SQUARE FEET                                Int64
LOT SIZE                                   Int64
YEAR BUILT                                 Int64
LATITUDE                                 Float64
LONGITUDE                                Float64
Age                                        Int64
TIME VAR UNIX                              Int64
is_Pandemic                              boolean
is_CY                                    boolean
dtype: object
```

However when trying to fit my XGBRegressor, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float or bool.
            Did not expect the data types in fields OHE_Cat__x0_Single Family Residential, OHE_Cat__x0_Townhouse, OHE_Cat__x1_1, OHE_Cat__x1_2, ZIP OR POSTAL CODE, BEDS, BATHS, SQUARE FEET, LOT SIZE, YEAR BUILT, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, Age, TIME VAR UNIX, is_Pandemic, is_CY
```

Oddly, this error was not present when I was using `pd.get_dummmies`, but after switching to `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` I started receiving it so I'm thinking there is in an error in my code below?

```
oneHotE = OneHotEncoder(drop='first')
transformer = ColumnTransformer([('OHE_Cat', oneHotE, categorical)], remainder = 'passthrough')
    
df = pd.DataFrame(transformer.fit_transform(df), columns= transformer.get_feature_names()).convert_dtypes()
```

I've tried the following alterations to my dataset before a `train_test_split`:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, axis=1)
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, axis=0)
df = df.convert_dtypes()
df = df.dropna()
df = df._get_numeric_data()
```

**EDIT**:

- `RandomForestRegressor` runs fine without errors, but gives the following warning:

> futurewarning: Arrays of bytes/strings is being converted to decimal
> numbers if dtype='numeric'. This behavior is deprecated in 0.24 and
> will be removed in 1.1 (renaming of 0.26). Please convert your data to
> numeric values explicitly instead.

- `CatBoostRegressor` gives the following error: `Cannot convert FloatingArray to numpy.ndarray`

Comment: What labels have you added in `categorical` ? I ask because I tried to recreate the error, on a dummy data, which was definitely not the best representation, but my code did run through without errors.

Comment: I have a kmeans cluster than is encoded to `OHE_Cat__x1_1` and `OHE_Cat__x1_2`. Property type is the other categorical variable.  `categorical = ['PROPERTY TYPE', 'kmn_cluster']`

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, this was originally the columns giving me trouble.

```
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   price      3400 non-null   Float64
 1   total      3400 non-null   Float64
 2   days       3400 non-null   Int64  
 3   inventory  3400 non-null   Int64
```

I got the same message saying these were not int, float or boolean, but they are. The issue is that there are not the type of int, float or boolean expected. After changing the types,

```
data['price'] = data['price'].astype(float)
data['total'] = data['total'].astype(float)
data['days'] = data['days'].astype(int)
data['inventory'] = data['inventory'].astype(int)
```

This is how the dtype columns shows:

```
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   price      3400 non-null   float64
 1   total      3400 non-null   float64
 2   days       3400 non-null   int32  
 3   inventory  3400 non-null   int32
```

I'm now able to do the training without issue. I only had 4 columns with this problem so it was a quick fix but there may be a better way if you need to do this change to a lot of columns.

Answer (score 0):

take all features to 'float' can solve, eg: df[feature] = df[feature].astype(float)